# Reading data from a non-MFi external accessory on iOS over USB-C port

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, usb, mfi

I'm trying to determine if I can read data from a non-MFi external accessory on an iPad with a USB-C connector. I've inferred from some things that I've read that while data transfer speeds may be limited from non-MFi external accessories, you can still read from them on USB-C iOS devices. Is this accurate? If so, would I need to use something other than the External Accessory Framework provided by Apple? It seems to me that the External Accessory Framework will only talk to MFi registered hardware - is there another way to listen directly to the USB-C port?

Thanks for any advice you could provide.

Comment: What sort of device are you trying to connect?  Some standard devices, like keyboards, mice, HDMI adapters and network adapters will work.  External storage and other types of peripheral won't.

Comment: It's a completely custom hardware device, was just hoping to be able to open the port and read from it.

Comment: No, it would definitely need to use an MFi chipset.